# Locale.getISOCountries() is returning different list in android devices (tested on samsung galaxy S10) JAVA

Tags: java, locale, iso, mobile-country-code

I'm currently using Locale.getISOCountries() to get ISO-compliant country code list. In android device when I print the output it was returning a different list, for example, it has some extra country codes
"ZWG"(Zawgyi), "SIL" (Silesian) but when I run the same code on Ideone platform these country codes were not present am I doing anything wrong? or is there any way to get standard ISO country code list?

here is the link to the code snippet. `getISO3CountryCodes()`

https://ideone.com/rEUclG

Comment: The official list is published by ISO. you may buy from them (or from the standardization body of your country). But it will be very expensive. The list of countries AND TERRITORIES is not stable. It changes from time to time (change of countries, but also changes of names).

Comment: I second @GiacomoCatenazzi and also I wonder why you did not choose the most voted answer from that question. Using that, your code can be simply `String[] checkForCountries = { "ZWG", "GLB", "SIL", "ANT", "GPL" };
  for (String iso3Country : checkForCountries) {
   System.out.println(Locale.getISOCountries(Locale.IsoCountryCode.PART1_ALPHA3).contains(iso3Country));
  }`

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash actually I'm using java 8 getISOCountries()  function is not taking any arguments.